# OWASP CSRF token with JSF ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, csrf, owasp

We secured our website using OWASP CSRF guard and configured TokenPerPage=true. We use JSF 2.0 (myfaces) for our front-end development.

Every thing works good as expected except when we use JSF ajax (). 
When we submit an ajax request from a page, the ajax request is successful but the **subsequent Http Request fails with a message**

> ("potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:%, ip:x.x.x.x, uri:/ppr/secured/xxxx.faces, error:request token does not match page token)").

**Below is my speculation :**

- In JSF the URL displayed in the browser address bar is always the previous page/request url ( as JSF 'POST' submits the request to same view and uses forward dispatcher). And any ajax request from a page uses the current page's url. May be the ajax request overrides the token.

For troubleshooting - I captured the request/response using fiddler and exported to a file. You can open it using fiddler.

[owasp-Jsf-Ajax-issue-1.saz](http://api.ning.com/files/72Jod1iYAGGSLkTz5bSGQvFlyZ4WFyZ9%2anH6Ff0UCVFjV5JtbFkp93WNzALEgYKcoXLlLT5dyMCZEfk0ZoNSTZoAsEq-n7Cx/dvwsb64owaspAjaxissue1.saz)

This image will help in describing the requests in the fiddler file.

[Fiddler_OWASP_CSRF_JSF_Ajax_issue.jpg](http://api.ning.com/files/72Jod1iYAGGZ9dsTntVKIyxMDSKDZXoKSFXsVAHu3n%2avPLM%2aVdLQl272g5nC3X8%2ay0R-PLak0bkCwVYilyUDIFlqzOL7tlfA/Fiddler_OWASP_CSRF_JSF_Ajax_issue.jpg)

JSF code -FYR :

```
<t:dataTable id="xyzTableId" value="#{varObject.additionalNotes}" var="additionalNote"><t:column>
       <h:inputText id="additionalNoteMsg" value="# {additionalNote.message}">
          <f:ajax event="blur" render="noteForm:xyzTableId:#{rowIndex}:displayId" onerror="printAjaxError" />
       </h:inputText></t:column>
</t:dataTable>
<t:commandButton type="button" value="Add Notes" id="button1"/>
```

Comment: Is it a POST or GET that fails?

Comment: the subsequent call that failed is a POST

Comment: My thought is that setting `TokenPerPage=true` is expiring the token once used. From a security standpoint, you only really need a token per user session as there is no way for an attacker to read the value.

Comment: Based on my analysis, OWASP script generate unique tokens per uri per session. Every time I hit a page within the same session I see the same token.  As you suggested, I would fall back to token per session if I couldn't resolve this issue.